# Confused with the theme editor , Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Can i ask how can I apply the 'theme in editor' as a theme on my Android Project that I am trying to make? 
[image: Theme in editor not synchronize with the project that I am trying to make]

Comment: It's a layout on your picture, not a theme. What do you want to apply?

Comment: @Psytho Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen this is the theme I want to apply?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can set a theme in your **AndroidManifest.xml**.
- If you only want to apply the theme in one activity you only need to change it in the **activity.xml**.
  -If you want to hide the ActionBar you can use any of the themes that allow **.NoActionBar**.
- If you're trying to change the colors you need to edit **colors.xml**.

For any question, reply.